# WSDL Not Loading in .NET WCF Service

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, web-services, wsdl

So I created a basic WCF Web Service, with one Operation Contract and a Data Contract, all built ok.  However after deploy to my test web server, an attempt to download the WSDL it redirects me to the main service screen or "You have created a service", nothing shows up in error messages or event logs, Fiddler reports nothing and while I can attach to the web service ok via remote debugging, no errors show up in code.  What are some other easy checks to see what is going on?  This is C# on the .NET 3.5 framework.

Comment: have you tried calling the service thru service reference to see if it works

Comment: actually yes, I was creating an InfoPath form via custom code talking to it, InfoPath couldn't read the WSDL either...

Comment: basic check: what does opening `http://yourserviceurl/yourservice.svc?wsdl` in a browser yield ?

Comment: Nothing but the default service page or "you have created a service" default that shows with any .NET page, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured it out, for some reason the code behind in the markup for the service was not set to the proper class.  Fixed.

Answer (score 4):

Make sure you have set the 'serviceMetadata' values correctly in the server web.config file.

```
<serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" httpsGetEnabled="true" />
```

depending on whether you want to expose via http and/or https

Answer (score 0):

Same happened here when I forget to decorate the service interface with [ServiceContract] attribute.